# Dividing two non-noisy signals by each other increases noise

Tags: noise

I am doing some signal processing on spectrum data.
A methodology I am following requires a ratio of a measured signal *S* and a reference signal *R.*

Both of these signals are quite clean but since both have a little noise centered around zero, the quantity *S/R* becomes very noisy.

I have tried filtering using many methods to no avail.

[image]

Comment: The question is a bit vague so would be hard to answer I think. It would be helpful if you could provide more specific details about the specific methodology you are following and expected versus actual result.

Comment: Especially if you're not 100% sure on how to answer Dan's question, it might be very very helpful if you could provide us with information *why* you need this ratio - one of the things DSP algorithm developers very consistently try to avoid *is* the division by things that get close to zero, so maybe we have a solution to the underlying problem, too!

Comment: Maybe a small epsilon term: `S / (R + 1e-5)`, but if R is both signs then `S / (sign(R) * (abs(R) + 1e-5))`.

Comment: I have tried using the epsilon term and it worked!